# Count number of rows from two columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

my CSV file is something like this

```
ProductID          competitor_1_price          competitor_2_price
    1                        100                      90
    2                                                230
    3                        340                     
    4           
    5                        45                       80
```

I want to count for how many products we have at least one competitor Price using pandas , here answer should be 4

Comment: If the missing values are NaN (np.nan), you can try df[['competitor_1_price','competitor_2_price']].any(1).sum(). Else first replace empty data by np.nan

Comment: how to calculate cells containing both columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. Just adjust the seperator of the csv file and also the kind of your empty cells (np.nan, '', etc) if they are different from the ones below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('name.csv', sep=' ')
result=len(df[(df['competitor_1_price']!=np.nan) | (df['competitor_1_price']!=np.nan)])
```

Comment: Above ans is not working

ProductID          competitor_1_price          competitor_2_price
    1                        100                      90
    2                                                230
    3                        340                     
    4           
    5                        45                       80

Comment: Strange.Can you provide a detailed example that is not working?